# function for checking if an unknown word appears in all 3 strings of different length

Tags: c, string, function

I pass 3 strings to the function and need look through the strings to find a word that appears in all three of them. The strings are just letters with no spaces or interpunction. I wrote a code to go through 2 strings but it doesn't work for some reason. Any help is appreciated.

```
char* najduljiPodniz(char* niz1, char* niz2, char* niz3)
{
   int i,j,t1,br=0;

   for(i=0;i<strlen(niz1);i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<strlen(niz2);j++)
       {
           if(niz1[i]==niz2[j])
           {
               t1=i;
               br++;
               while(niz1[i]==niz2[j])
               {
                   br++;
                   i++;
                   j++;
               }
           }
           else break;
       }
   }

char *podniz=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*br+1);

for(i=0,j=t1;j<br;i++,j++)
    podniz[i]=niz1[j];

for(i=0;i<br;i++)
    printf("%s",podniz[i]);

return 0;
}
```

For clarification: Example of a string would be: "afsdmartiangknrhg". So, random letters and somewhere in the string there's an actual word. In this example "martian". The other 2 strings also contain the word "martian". The word martian is "unkown" to me so I can't check for that actual word in the string.

Comment: How do you know something is a 'word' if there are no spaces?

Comment: OP's problem is not searching for a known substring. It's identifying an unknown substring that occurs in all three strings. This is actually an interesting problem that might have a semi-efficient solution despite all the obvious solutions being either very slow or using cheats like hashes that make them "look fast".

Comment: @R.. - Good point. However as it stands it's a poorly defined problem. How long is a "word"? "a" is a letter, but it can also be an indefinite article, thus a "word".

Comment: I read "The strings are just letters with no spaces or interpunction" as a poor way of trying to say that words are sequences of letters delimited by non-letters.

Comment: I added a clarification to the first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's my new answer based on the revised description of the problem (see the comments on my first answer).

First, choose the shortest of the three strings. Iterate over all possible substrings of this string, starting with the longest. For each substring, use `strstr` to search for it in the other two strings. If it's found in both, you have your solution.

Try something like:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<=i; j++) {
        int tmp = a[N-1-i+j];
        a[N-1-i+j] = 0;
        if (strstr(b, a+j) && strstr(c, a+j)) printf("got '%s'\n", a+j);
        a[N-1-u+j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I enter these 3 strings: "sohosumartianhifhuish", "iuhmartiansbgdifohisduf" and "piundniorgcoimartian" the program with this code prints all the common substrings starting from the longest one. So I should break the loop when it prints the 1st substring. But when I enter shorter strings like "bjtikf", "gftik" and "dntikknv", the common substring is "tik" but it prints the following "ti", "t", "i, "","","","". Is the "N" in your code the length of the shortest string?

Comment: Yes, `N` is the length of the shortest string `a`.

Comment: Alrighty, I added "goto end;" and "end:" after this part of the code to end the program after printing the first substring because I don't know how else to end it but this works. Thank you and everyone else for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to start with the shortest string (measured in word count) and iterate over each word in this string. For each word, call `strstr` to attempt to find it in both of the other strings, with a little extra work to check that it's at a word boundary and resume the search if you found it embedded in a larger word.

I suppose this has decent performance; it's quadratic in the total number of characters, but you can bound it better than that; it's roughly `O(N*M)` where `N` is the number of words in the string with the fewest words and `M` is the total number of characters. (Note: I'm assuming linear-time `strstr`, not one of the quadratic algorithms.)

Comment: "...iterate over each word in this string." If the string looks like this: "afsdmartiangknr", I can't iterate over each word because there's just this one "word".

Comment: Sure you can. There's one iteration.

Comment: But if the first string is "afsdmartiangknr" and the second is "oinjgtmartianbgrj" they will never be the same because strstr checks wether the whole strings are the same, right?

Comment: I thought that was the whole point.. If I'm mistaken, please clarify your question. Are you looking for the largest matching substring? If you just want **any** substring that appears in all 3 strings, then the problem reduces to just finding a single character that appears in all 3 strings, and that's a trivial problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for not explaining well.  Example of a string would be: "afsdmartiangknrhg". So, random letters and somewhere in the string there's an actual word. In this example "martian". The other 2 strings also contain the word "martian". The word martian is "unkown" to me so I can't check for that actual word in the string. All 3 strings will contain only 1 same substring.

Comment: In that case, all three strings also contain the word "art". Is that a valid answer, or are you looking for the *maximum-length* substring contained in all three?

Comment: I'm looking for the maximum length.

Comment: @Filip: so you want the longest common substring that's a "word"? Does "actual word" mean "appears in a dictionary"? Specifically, what is the correct output if the input strings are "martianga", "martiangb" and "martiangc"? Is it "martian" or "martiang"?

Comment: I want the longest commong substring for all 3 strings. The substring will definately be a normal word. The correct output would be "martiang" in this case but the strings entered will contain a word like "martian" with different letters around it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions here.  "Why doesn't my program work?" and "How can I solve this problem?"

For the first question, the main problem is that your inner while loop increments `i` and `j`, which means that if you find any common characters between `niz1` and `niz2`, you'll skip the following characters in the outer loop(s) and never look for substrings containing them.  For example, if `niz1` is "afsdmartiangknrhg" and `niz2` contains a 'd' anywhere, you'll skip the 'm' in 'martian' in `niz1`, and thus never look to match that substring in `niz2`

For the second question, it sounds like your problem reduces to: Given a string x and a set of strings y_1..y_n, find the longest substring of x which is present in all of y_1..y_n.  So the obvious solution becomes:

1. pick the shortest of your input strings and call that 'x'.  Call the rest y_1..y_n.
2. For every substring of x, from longest to shortest, check if it is present in all of y_1..y_n.  If you find one, you're done.  If not, continue with possibly shorter substrings

This will require O(n * k^2) substring checks where n is the number of strings and k is the length of the shortest.  Each substring check will likely take O(k) time itself, so O(n * k^3) overall -- quite slow, but if your shortest string is short, may be ok.